# Does the partion location change automatically when the athena table's location is changed?

Tags: amazon-athena

I have created one table test and its partion with this location is `s3://mocktest/test`

Now, I want to update my table location to `s3://mocktest/test-new`
so that I used `ALTER TABLE test set LOCATION s3://mocktest/test-new` query
location is updated in test table but not in the partion table.

> 'MSCK REPAIR TABLE' command not working for update the partion

Answer (score 2):

The location of existing partitions is not related to the location of the table. If you want to move the location of all partitions you need to change each of them individually. When you run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE …` after changing the location of a table it will look for new partitions in the new location, but not change any existing partitions.